# Quartz.net Shutdown shut all Schedulers

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I use Quartz.net to create 5 Schedulers in a Windows Service.
But when I want to shutdown one of my Schedulers, it shut them all.

Here is my class :

```
internal class Scheduler
{
    private IScheduler shed;
    public SchedulerConfig config { get; private set; }

    internal Scheduler(SchedulerConfig config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }

    internal void Schedule()
    {
        ISchedulerFactory sf = new Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory();
        shed = sf.GetScheduler();

        Type T = config.job;

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create(T)
            .WithIdentity("job_" + config.name, "groupScheduler")
            .Build();

        string cronExpression = config.cronExpression;

        ICronTrigger trigger = (ICronTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                    .WithIdentity("trigger_" + config.name, "groupScheduler")
                                    .WithCronSchedule(cronExpression)
                                    .Build();

        job.JobDataMap.Put("SchedulerConfig", config);

        DateTimeOffset ft = shed.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

        shed.Start();
    }

    internal void Stop()
    {
        if (shed != null && !shed.IsShutdown)
        {
            shed.Shutdown(false);
            shed = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The schedulers use a differant 'SchedulerConfig', with a differant 'Name'.

Is it because they all have the same Group Name ?

When i call the 'Stop' method, the IShcheduler of this object is null, but the others are shutdown too.

Before the call, they all have :

- IsStandByMode = false
- IsShutdown = false
- IsStarted = true

After the call, one is null and the 4 others have :

- IsStandByMode = true
- IsShutdown = true
- IsStarted = true

Do you have any idea to find the solution about this problem ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

When you create scheduler instance you should give it unique instance name. This way you can shutdown specific scheduler and not all of them. Check StdSchedulerFactory.GetScheduler method sources and you will understand everything.

```
        var props = new NameValueCollection
    {
        {"quartz.scheduler.interruptJobsOnShutdownWithWait", "true"},
        {"quartz.scheduler.instanceName", nameof(CheckPricesScheduler)}
    };

    var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go through quartz documentation you will find that `shed.Shutdown(false);` is not the correct way to stop some particular trigger or job.Shutdown method will

```
 Halts the Scheduler's firing of Triggers, and cleans up all resources associated with the Scheduler.
```

so to stop individual jobs or trigger please use `pauseJob(JobKey jobKey)`,`pauseJobs(GroupMatcher<JobKey> matcher)`,`pauseTrigger(TriggerKey triggerKey)` and `pauseTriggers(GroupMatcher<TriggerKey> matcher)` methods

i have referred java docs for the above function please look for similar method for c# library for quartz project.